# Passing Jade Mixins as Parameters to other Jade Mixins

Tags: pug

I'm designing a website for a client using the principles of [atomic design](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/). I'm creating an organism that may contain different molecules within it. My question is, can this organism take molecule mixins as arguments? Something like this, for example:

**Molecule1**

```
mixin molecule-1(args)
  .someDiv(class= args.class)
    p= args.text
```

**Molecule2**

```
mixin molecule-2(args)
  .someOtherDiv(class= args.class)
    p= args.text
    a(href='#')= args.linkText
```

**Organism**

```
mixin organism(slides)

  include path/to/molecule-1.jade
  include path/to/molecule-2.jade

  .container
    each slide in slides
      slide
```

**Page**

```
include path/to/organism.jade
include path/to/molecule-1.jade
include path/to/organism.jade

+organism({slides:[+molecule-1({class: 'someclass', text: 'sometext'}), 
                   +molecule-2({class: 'someotherclass', text: 'sometext',
                                linkText: 'someLink'})]})
```

which would yield

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='someDiv someclass'>
        <p>sometext</p>
    </div>
    <div class='someOtherDiv someotherclass'>
        <p>sometext</p>
        <a href='#'>someLink</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or do I have to pass in each individual attribute to the organism like so:

**Organism**

```
 mixin organism(slides)

  include path/to/molecule-1.jade
  include path/to/molecule-2.jade

  .container
    each slide in slides
      if slide.type === 'molecule1'
        +molecule-1({class: slide.class, text: slide.text})
      else if slide.type === 'molecule2'
        +molecule-2({class: slide.class, text: slide.text, linkText: slide.linkText})
```

In other words, is there a more elegant solution to the problem than the latter way of doing things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I got to work. I think you do need an `if` statement in `organism` to figure out which molecule to render, and a `type` attribute in each object, but then you can just pass the object straight to the appropriate molecule mixin.

You can also use the [rest arguments syntax](http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins/) (...slides) to pass in an unspecified number of arguments.

```
include path/to/molecule-1.jade
include path/to/molecule-2.jade

mixin organism(...slides)
    .container
        each slide in slides
            if slide.type == "m1"
                +molecule-1(slide)
            else if slide.type == "m2"
                +molecule-2(slide)

+organism({type:"m1", class:"class1", text:"some text"}, {type:"m2", class:"class2", text:"some more text", linkText:"Link"})
```

You can make the `organism` call a little more readable by splitting out the molecule objects into variables if you want.

```
- var moleculeObj1 = {type:"m1", class:"class1", text:"some text"};
- var moleculeObj2 = {type:"m2", class:"class2", text:"some more text", linkText:"Link"};

+organism(moleculeObj1, moleculeObj2)
```